# need help with using stristr

Tags: php, string, find, position

I need help return everything after "I can read." I understand that this will search the string and find whats in the array `$check` but how do I make it check and then return all whats found after "I can read"?

```
$string = "I can read. I can count. I can spell.";
$check = array("I can count.", "I can't count.");
$find = stristr($string, $check, true);
echo $find;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$find = 'I can read.';
$string = '[...]';

echo substr($string,stripos($string,$find)+strlen($find));
```

Comment: Thanks just what I needed. Accepted your answer.

Comment: note you can use stristr but second param should be just a simple string

Answer (score 1):

Here is what the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) say the second parameter (needle) of `stistr`:

> If needle is not a string, it is converted to an integer and applied as
>   the ordinal value of a character.

Then you have to define `$check` as follow:

```
$check = "I can read";
```

you do not need the third parameter if you want to get the substring after `$check`, [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) states:

> If TRUE, stristr() returns the part of the haystack before the
>   first occurrence of the needle.

That's why you have to call `stristr` with only two arguments:

```
$find = stristr($string, $check);
```

Comment: it described on the last line of code, just use stristr with the string you are searching in and the needle